# Fill two inputs in parallel using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do simple task of filling two inputs at once such that when one input is filled by user the other input gets filled with same data automatically. 
Here is the javascript code

```
function autofilltitle(){
    var title_en=document.getElementById('title_en');
    var title_id=document.getElementById('title_id');
    var title_pt_br=document.getElementById('title_pt-br');
    var data =title_en.value;
    title_id.value=title_en.value;
    title_pt_br.value= title_en.value;
}
```

I have tried this at W3schools editor and it is working fine there. But on my local machine it is not functional. Console gives no errors but the task is not completed.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" value=""name="title_en" id="title_en" data-required="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" onkeyup="autofilltitle()" />
<input type="text" value=""name="title_pt-br" id="title_pt-br" data-required="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" onkeyup="autofilltitle()" />
<input type="text" value=""name="title_id" id="title_id" data-required="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" onkeyup="autofilltitle()" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by "here"?

Comment: share the html as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an eventlistener on the input element.

If the eventListener is not set, the function won't run automatically

```js
function autofilltitle(){
    var title_en=document.getElementById('title_en');
    var title_id=document.getElementById('title_id');
    var title_pt_br=document.getElementById('title_pt-br');
    var data =title_en.value;
    title_id.value=title_en.value;
    title_pt_br.value= title_en.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="title_en" onkeyup="autofilltitle()" />
<input id="title_id" />
<input id="title_pt-br" />
```

Comment: No I am not. I have added the event listener and double checked that am I reaching the function or not.

Comment: then add the HTML

Comment: `console.log(title_en)` gives no value

Comment: do you want to copy data from input#title_en ?

Comment: I want data that is inserted into #title_en to be in other

Comment: then add the event listener only to that. remove from others

Comment: `console.log(title_en)` won't give any value because of scope issue

Comment: try `console.log(document.getElementById('title_en').value)`

Comment: This is dynamic content. the ids are getting generated dynamically from php is that an issue?

Comment: I don't think so since you added inline onkeyup event

Comment: whatever it displays on console is either undefined or empty.